# Problem when trying to read EXCEL after implementing OFFICE 365 "Confidentiality Label"

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, apache-hop

I have an ETL routine in PENTAHO and I'm migrating to APACHE HOP.

But I came across a situation, the HOP step/plugin "`Microsoft Excel Input`" cannot read the data before I open the excel file and click confirm **Add Confidentiality Label**.

In PENTAHO PDI this problem does not occur, does anyone have any tips?

IMG 1
[image]

After clicking and adding a confidentiality label like "public" for example and saving and closing the file, the process works perfectly.

Note: This only happens with some files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem that will not have a clear and direct answer and will require some changes in the code.

The code for Apache Hop is managed on [Github](https://github.com/apache/hop).
You can create an issue there and one of the developers will help you get this sorted out. When creating a ticket please be as specific as you can be and add a sample, that will improve the chances of getting a fix on short notice.